# Login for Icenium Ion App is Wonky

Tags: cordova, icenium

It welcomes me even if I enter a gibberish password.

Since the Icenium Mist site allowed me to "sign in via Facebook" but the Ion app offers no similar functionality, I don't even know that I have a proper dedicated Icenium login to enter.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Ion does not require login. It is just a container app in which you can run your project to test it on an iOS device without having to build it with a provisioning profile and a cryptographic identity.

Running your apps in Ion is pretty straightforward:

1. Install Ion on your device from the Apple App Store.
2. Install a QR code reader on your device. Note that some QR code readers cause problems. QRReader and RedLaser have been reported to work properly.
3. In Mist, create and modify your project.
4. In the main menu, click **Run** -> **Build** and select **Icenium Ion**.
5. Wait for the build to complete and scan the QR code with your device.
6. Tap the link to open it. Icenium Ion should launch automatically with your app loaded.

Hope that helps,
Iva